# Count a particular letter from a sentence/ Paragraph using SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a sentence like "John is very good at SQL Server and Dot NET and Florida is from France." I want to read this sentence using SQL Server and count how many f's are there. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by replacing the letter with a string one character longer, measuring the length and comparing to the original length:

```
select (len(replace(sentence, 'f', 'ff')) - len(sentence)) as NumFs
```

EDIT (in response to Soner):

The case sensitivity of `replace` depends on the collation of the inputs (see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)).  If you need a particular case sensitivity, then use `collate`.

As for why I write it this way.  There are two reasons.  I used to do the calculations as you suggest in the comment.  But then I realized that the important part of the expression (the replace) was at the end.  Often, that meant that I just couldn't readily see what the expression was doing.

Second, when you want to count something longer than a single character, replacing with `''` isn't quite right -- you either have to divide by the length or find a shorter character string.

So, the above method is what I use in general for counting substrings in strings.

Comment: Or `select len(sentence)) - (len(replace(sentence, 'f', ''))` or course `:)` By the way Gordon, `Replace` is case sensitive? In this case, your solution makes `France` to `FFrance`? I couldn't find any information on [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx).

Comment: @GordonLinoff : Thanks a lot for your support. I have got the result.